# insert a variable in an html file embedded in a php file

Tags: php, html

this code shows a set of html statements embedded in a php file. Here in the second line i want that reference (href) value to be a variable depending upon the loop value ($i). But when I click on the link it goes to $i.html instead of going to the value in $i. please help

```
echo '<li>
          <div class="imgholder">
             <a href= "$i.html">
                <img src="images/demo/imgl.png" alt="" />
             </a>
           </div>
           <div class="latestnews">
              <h2>Text 1</h2>
              <p>Text 2</p>
           </div>
           <br class="clear" />
      </li>';
```

Comment: Lear about concatenation using single and double quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 echo "<li>
   <div class='imgholder'><a href= '$i.html'>
   <img src='images/demo/imgl.png' /></a></div>
        <div class='latestnews'>
          <h2>Text 1</h2>
          <p>Text 2</p>
         </div>
        <br class='clear' />
      </li>"
```

Answer (score 4):

There is concatenation operator ('.'), which returns the concatenation of its right and left arguments. Try with `.`:

```
echo '<li>
       <div class="imgholder"><a href= "'. $i  .'.html">
       <img src="images/demo/imgl.png" alt="" /></a></div>
            <div class="latestnews">
              <h2>Text 1</h2>
              <p>Text 2</p>
             </div>
            <br class="clear" />
          </li>';
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
echo '<li>
       <div class="imgholder"><a href= "'.$i.'.html">
       <img src="images/demo/imgl.png" alt="" /></a></div>
            <div class="latestnews">
              <h2>Text 1</h2>
              <p>Text 2</p>
             </div>
            <br class="clear" />
          </li>';
```

You have to concatenate the PHP variable with the HTML tags. You got `href` as `$i.html` as the value of the variable was not substituted correctly.

Answer (score 1):

How about you make it like this:

```
<?php for($i = 0; $i<10; $i++){ ?>
<li>
    <div class="imgholder">
        <a href="<?php echo $i; ?>.html"> <img src="images/demo/imgl.png" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="latestnews">
        <h2>Text 1</h2>
        <p>Text 2</p>
    </div> <br class="clear" />
</li>
<?php } ?>
```

In this context you have $i is a static String. But you want to have a variable which is dynamically changing.

Edited: Something like this is what I used to do, but it is not "clean" php.

Comment: Maybe include how this will be inside a loop

Comment: Edited it, not really pretty, but might work for his problem.

Comment: Probably got the question wrong, this would create everything in the <li> tag as many times as given (10 here) with a different link each time.

Answer (score 0):

use double quotes or concatenation, as mentioned before.

But I'd like to recomend you to take a look on templates
like [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/) or [twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/documentation), or even plain php